# Use Regex to get last substring, separated by hyphens

Tags: regex, parsing, google-bigquery

I need to parse out the "permission" substring from group names, however I have two patterns this group names follow:

```
gcp-edp-platform-dgov-nonprod-oneil-(permission)
gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-atp-(permission).groups
```

Either the group name ends with the permission substring, or it ends with the permission substring.groups.

I need to be able to extract just the permission substring without grabbing the `.groups`.

I know just `.*-(.*)` get me everything after the last hyphen but it still grabs the .groups for the names that do have it. Can someone help me create a regex for this instance?

Comment: Change your regex to: `.*-[^.]+` - `[^.]+` means on or more characters not being a dot `.`. This will match the rest in line1 and up to dot `.` in line 2.

Comment: Or for extracting what's inside parentheses to [`.*-\(([^)(]+)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/qtzSzX/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
.*-(.*?)(?:[.]groups)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P93bnw/1). *Details*:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?:[.]groups)?` - an optional sequence of `.groups`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Use look arounds:

```
(?<=-)[^-.]+(?!.*-)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/N1K2H0hdr5SWUF).

This works with the examples given (ie assumes permissions does not contain dashes or dots).